# JSON ToObject with SecureString

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm having trouble serializing JSON text to an object that contains a SecureString variable. How might I serialize the following whilst keeping the public 'pwd' variable a SecureString?

Let's say have the following string:

```
string j_str = "{ 'uid':'JohnDoe', 'age':30, 'pwd':'MyPassword' }";
```

and I would like to serialize this string into an object I have in C#

```
public class User
{
   public string uid = { get; set; }
   public string age = { get; set; }
   public SecureString pwd = { get; set; }
}
```

So I may the following call using the JSON ToObject) call with Newtonsoft like so:

```
JObject j_obj = JObject.Parse(j_str);

User newUser = j_obj.ToObject<User>();
```

This results in the following error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "MyPassword" to type 'System.Security.SecureString'. Path 'pwd'
```

Comment: Change the type of `pwd` property to `string`

Comment: _"whilst keeping the public 'pwd' variable a SecureString?"_ - That looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Because passwords are secrets to be kept in SecureString to avoid disclosure by memory dump and alike attacks. This said there is no default json serializer for SecureString which would know how to keep the secret secret, so one would also need to implement a custom json serializer for SecureString that would do something like encryption so the resulting json doesn't reveal the secret in clear text.

Answer (score 6):

Constructing this from a string would seem to go against the principle behind using a SecureString. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx:

> A SecureString object should never be constructed from a String,
>   because the sensitive data is already subject to the memory
>   persistence consequences of the immutable String class. The best way
>   to construct a SecureString object is from a character-at-a-time
>   unmanaged source, such as the Console.ReadKey method.

Comment: Would seem, if the string is a clear text password. However if you serialize/de-serialize to and from encrypted string, you are not leaking the clear text secret to memory. Furthermore there are many instances were you cannot keep a secret at all times in SecureString so you temporarily extract it to or construct from a string after which you can pin the string in unsafe code block to zero it out. Lots of example and code samples for that, including many here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

As said earlier, this does go against the principle of a SecureString. But here is a JSON converter for SecureString you can use.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public class SecureStringConverter : JsonConverter<SecureString>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, SecureString value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(value);
        writer.WriteValue(Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(ptr));
        Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(ptr);
    }

    public override SecureString ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, SecureString existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string json_val = (string)reader.Value;
        SecureString s = new SecureString();

        if (json_val != null) 
        {
            foreach (char c in json_val) 
            {
                s.AppendChar(c);
            }
        }
        s.MakeReadOnly();
        return s;
    }
}
```

To Serialize user:

```
string serialized_user = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, new SecureStringConverter());
```

To Deseralize serialized_user:

```
User deserialized_user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(serialized_user, new SecureStringConverter());
```